# All buttons do not show

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Crisis extends JFrame {

    public Crisis() {
        super("Crisis");
        setLookAndFeel();
        setSize(348, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        panicButton = new JButton("Panic");
        dontPanicButton = new JButton("Don't Panic");
        blameButton = new JButton("Blame Others");
        mediaButton = new JButton("Notify the Media");
        saveButton = new JButton("Save Yourself");
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout moo = new BorderLayout();
        pane.setLayout(moo);
        pane.add(panicButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pane.add(dontPanicButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(pane);
        FlowLayout flo = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10);
        JPanel noo = new JPanel();
        noo.setLayout(flo);
        noo.add(blameButton);
        noo.add(mediaButton);
        noo.add(saveButton);
        add(noo);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        new Crisis();
    }
}
```

**panicButton and dontPanicButton don't show in GUI**

Comment: The problem statement is clear from the title *All buttons do not show* and It's complete testable code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Braj That doesn't change the fact that it is a code dump with no effort on the side of the OP to solve the problem.

Comment: As you are aware of the fact that sometime a very silly mistake in the code can waste hours to find it. Sometime it happens with me as well and might be with you...

Comment: @Braj While that may be true, there is a new close reason that describes this post quite accurately.  Including an MCVE is very useful, but the question should also state the expected & actual behavior as well as what else was tried, to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) by default uses [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) and you can add only single component in each portion north, south, west, east and center.

You are adding two component in the center and only last one will be visible.

```
add(pane); // Added in center
...
add(noo);  // Added in center and replaced last one     <<-- Here is the problem
```

Add it in different portion (segment) or use another layout that suits as per your need.

---

Read more

- [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html)